# Connecting a bluebooth wristband button to android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am trying to connect my app to a bluetooth device. The device is a wristband with a button from another company (which has provided me with UUIDs) to connect to their device. We are looking to having the button on the wristband launch an action in the app.

However when I try to connect the app to the device I am getting

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

And if I try to read data I am getting an infinate loop of

```
java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
```

The code in my Activity is as follows

```
void openConnection() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002A19-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
}


void readData() throws IOException
{
    ct = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
    ct.start();
}
```

The Thread then consists of:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                //        .sendToTarget();
                Log.e("test", "recevied");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("test", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

The UUIDs I got from the manufacturer are the following. Not sure if these are actually useful to read button clicks on the device. I tried replacing the UUID string to match these UUIDs (example 0000FFD0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) but no luck.

```
Battery service UUID??0x180F
Eigenvalue UUID??0x2A19

Motor Service UUID??0xFFD0
Motor strength eigenvalue UUID??0xFFD1
High 0x03??Mid 0x02??low 0x01??
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The standard GUID/UUID for RFCOMM/SPP Serial Profile is {00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}...
Anyway, one way to 'know' about the services exposed by your device would be to:
1) make an Inquiry of nearby devices
2) find your wristband in the list (by name or MacAddress)
3) then do a Discovery on **this** device to enumerate all available services (SDP).
Then you'll know exactly who they are and you'll be able to connect to them using a 'discovered' and not 'hard-code' GUID. 
Only my suggestion... ;)